how do I find the dimension of the span of the intersection/union of two null spaces of different sizes of matrices using numpy/scipy?
I need to find $dim(span(H\cap G))$ and $dim(span(H\cup G))$ where H and G are defined the following way:

I have no idea how to find the intersection/union of their null spaces and after that, I don't know how to find the span and dim.
matrix A has sizes of 5X18, and matrix B - 8X18.
This is what I tried using the null_space of Scipy; it seems like it does find the null spaces but fails in the intersection part, and I didn't find a dedicated intersection/union function.
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from scipy.linalg import null_space

A = np.matrix([[2 ,0 ,3 ,-1 ,2 ,-1 ,6 ,-4 ,7 ,8 ,-1 ,-4 ,7 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,7 ],
               [-6 ,-7 ,-9 ,10 ,1 ,10 ,-4 ,12 ,-7 ,4 ,-4 ,5 ,-7 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,7 ,0 ],
               [10 ,0 ,8 ,-12 ,-4 ,-5 ,-5 ,-13 ,0 ,5 ,2 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,7 ,0 ,0],
               [8 ,0 ,5 ,-4 ,1 ,-4 ,3 ,-9 ,7 ,11 ,3 ,-2 ,7 ,0 ,7 ,0 ,0 ,0 ],
               [-9 ,-7 ,-3 ,8 ,5 ,8 ,1 ,11 ,0 ,-1 ,1 ,-3 ,0 ,7 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ]])

B = np.matrix([[3 ,2 ,3 ,-1 ,5 ,-5 ,2 ,0 ,-3 ,5 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,2 ],
             [39 ,26 ,27 ,-13 ,29 ,-25 ,-4 ,-2 ,-7 ,21 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,32 ,0 ],
             [-5 ,18 ,31 ,-9 ,25 ,-5 ,12 ,-26 ,5 ,17 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,32 ,0 ,0 ],
             [25 ,6 ,21 ,-3 ,19 ,-23 ,4 ,-14 ,-9 ,27 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,16 ,0 ,0 ,0 ],
             [-3 ,-6 ,-3 ,1 ,-5 ,1 ,-4 ,2 ,3 ,-1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,4 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ],
             [-47 ,-10 ,-35 ,5 ,-53 ,17 ,4 ,-14 ,79 ,-13 ,0 ,0 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ],
             [67 ,66 ,71 ,-33 ,81 ,-61 ,76 ,-10 ,-67 ,41 ,0 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ],
             [59 ,18 ,31 ,-41 ,57 ,-37 ,12 ,6 ,-59 ,49 ,32 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ]])

An = null_space(A)
Bn = null_space(B)

intersect = An[np.where(An==Bn)]
print(intersect)


Why the sympy import?  Numeric and symbolic packages are poorly integrated.

What's the expected output? Can you add it to the question? Do you only want the dimensions?

@hpaulj it was used in another question where it was required, it's not required here.

@user24714692 I don't know the answer, I would love to be able to print every step of the way for my understanding and debugging but yeah I only need the final solution (which is the dim(span(intersect(H,G)))

Keep in mind you have several kinds of readers.  A few have worked with this kind of problem before, and can answer without much thinking or research.  Others are interested enough to copy-n-paste your example into an interactive session and explore the intermediate values.  I for one, would like to see those debugging values first (I don't always read these questions from my computer).  Then there are thow whose 30 second attention span runs out before they understand this problem. :)

@hpaulj you are right but in this assignment im only supposed to give final answers (it's a web assignment)

The intersection of the null spaces is spanned by a set of vectors vi for which both A @ vi = 0 and B @ vi = 0, where 0 represents a zero vector of appropriate size. You can find the vi by stacking the two matrices and taking the null space.
Cn = null_space(np.vstack((A, B)))
np.testing.assert_allclose(A @ Cn, 0, atol=5e-14)
np.testing.assert_allclose(B @ Cn, 0, atol=5e-14)
# both tests pass

You can get a set of vectors that spans the union of the null spaces by pooling the null space vectors (i.e. stacking the An and Bn that you found).
np.vstack((An.T, Bn.T))

In general, however, these vectors will not be linearly independent. If you want a minimal set of vectors that span the union of the null spaces, the most concise way I can think of is to take the null space of the null space of these vectors.
Dn = null_space(null_space(np.vstack((An.T, Bn.T))).T)

np.linalg.matrix_rank finds the dimensionality of the span of a set of vectors.
# note that it doesn't matter whether we transpose or not
np.linalg.matrix_rank(Cn)  # 7
np.linalg.matrix_rank(Dn)  # 16

If you just needed the dim of the span of the union, you don't really need to remove the redundancies before taking the rank.
np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.vstack((An.T, Bn.T)))  # 16

Of course, there are probably more revealing/satisfying solutions using explicit matrix decompositions, but this is the most concise way I can think of.

is that for the intersection/union? and then how do I find the dim(span())?

I updated my answer. It's been a very long time since I've taken linear algebra, so you might want to post on math stack exchange to get a better explanation.

just to clarify, the rank of Cn is equal to the intersection, and the rank of Dn is equal to the union?

Yes. Please do study the theory, though, if this is an assignment. You can infer that Cn is the intersection just from the fact that an intersection would be smaller than a union and 7 is smaller than 16.
